# Swift iOS GoogleMaps CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not updating camera

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location, google-maps-sdk-ios, cllocation

I'm new to iOS and am building a very simple iOS using swift 5.7.2 and XCode 14.2.

The app basically needs to show a Google Map View as the user's device travels around. I have successfully made the view and enabled location service and the Map now shows my location on the map. The blue icon also tracks my location as I move around.

However, even though the blue icon representing my position moves around, the map itself doesn't move around and that can result in my position being outside of the map if I have travelled far enough.

My UIViewController is:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var manager: CLLocationManager?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager?.delegate = self
        manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        let currentCoordinate = manager?.location?.coordinate
        let viewBounds = self.view.bounds
        let screenCenter = CGPoint(x: viewBounds.midX, y: viewBounds.midY)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: currentCoordinate?.latitude ?? 51.0447, longitude: currentCoordinate?.longitude ?? -114.0719, zoom: 9.0)
        let navView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 130, y: 10, width: viewBounds.maxX - 135 * 2, height: viewBounds.maxY - 20), camera: camera)
        navView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(navView)
    }
    
}
```

And the app looks like:
[image: App View Google Maps]

What I think is wrong:

I am not using `didUpdateLocations` of `locationManager` to update the camera position as I am not sure what's the proper way of doing it. Throwing this code inside `UIViewController` doesn't work:

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print(locValue)

    }
```

What's the proper way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature is wrong (it's Swift 2 outdated for a long time).

Please have a look at a the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager), the current signature is

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last!
    print(location.coordinate)
}
```

and the updated locations are in the `locations` parameter.

And to avoid the optional replace

```
var manager: CLLocationManager?
```

with

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
```

and remove `manager = CLLocationManager()` and the question marks